# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar un carácter por otro en una cadena sin utilizar .replace?

Tags: java, string

El problema es ese, debo de cambiar un carácter de una cadena pero sin usar .replace o alguna variación
Es como simularlo y se me ha ocurrido un ciclo que recorra toda la cadena y cuando encuentre dicho carácter lo sustituye.

```
   public String reemplazaCaracter(String cadena, char reemplazado, char reemplazador){ 
    int indice = 0;
    String resultado =  cadena;
    while (indice <= cadena.length()-1){

        if (cadena.charAt(indice) == reemplazado){
        //char nuevo = reemplazador;??
        //cadena.charAt(indice) = nuevo;??
        indice++;
         }

        indice++;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es una solución, defines la palabra, la letra que deseas reemplazar y la letra que reemplazarías:

```
 public static String reemplazaCaracter(String str, String reemplazado, String reemplazador ) {
    char charToreplace = reemplazado.charAt(0);
    String output = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {         
         if( str.charAt(i) == charToreplace) {
             output += reemplazador; 
             str.substring(i+1, str.length());
         }else{
             output += str.charAt(i);
        }            
    }
    return output;
}
```

Como salida obtendrías una cadena con el carácter especificado reemplazado en tu cadena.

Ejemplo:

```
   System.out.println(replaceLetter("José Boxrdxles" , "x", "a"));
```

salida:

```
José Boardales
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con `StringBuilder`:

Mira este ejemplo

En este caso Reemplazado seria la letra "a" y el reemplazador seria "X", aunque la forma mas facil y en la que podrias utilizar String es `replace`, pero tienes esta opcion:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Holaa Como Estaas");
        for(int i = 0;i<sb.length();i++){
            char ch = sb.charAt(i);
            if(ch == 'a'){
                sb.setCharAt(i,'X');
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes convertir el `String` en un array de `char`, luego recorrerlo e ir reemplazando el caracter cuando lo encuentres. Luego conviertes el array de vuelta a `String` y lo retornas. Así:

```
public static String reemplazaCaracter(String cadena, char reemplazado, char reemplazador){
    char[] array = cadena.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] == reemplazado)
            array[i] = reemplazador;
    }
    return new String(array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > ¿Cómo puedo cambiar un carácter por otro en una cadena sin utilizar .replace?

**Una posible solución** es recorrer la cadena e ir verificando si el caracter (`oldChar`) que se quiere reemplazar se encuentra en la cadena y si llegara a ser verdadero, pues se crea un nuevo objeto de tipo `String`, en la cual, incluiremos (se concatena) el caracter (`newChar`) que lo va a reemplazar.

Si el caracter (`oldChar`) no se llegara a encontrar en la cadena, nuestro método `replace` retornará la misma cadena.

En código quedaría de esta manera:

```java
class MyString
{
    private String str;

    public MyString(String str)
    {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
    {
        String newString = "";
        int len = str.length();
        for(int i = 0; i != len; ++i)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i) == oldChar) 
                newString += newChar;
            else
                newString += str.charAt(i);
        }
        return newString;
    }
}
```

La forma de invocar al método `replace` sería de esta forma:

```java
public class Program 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MyString str = new MyString("Heaao Worad!");
        //Como la letra 'a' si se encuentra en la cadena, se lo reemplazará por 'l'
        System.out.println(str.replace('a', 'l'));
        //Como la letra 'z' no se encuentra en la cadena, el método retorna la misma cadena
        System.out.println(str.replace('z', 'l'));
    }
}
```

**Resultado por pantalla:**

```java
Hello World!
Heaao Worad!
```

Como sabemos, la clase `String` hace que los objetos sean inmutables, por ende, no hay forma de modificar el contenido del objeto y por esa razón, en cada iteración debemos crear un nuevo objeto a través de la concatenación, es decir, con el operador `+=`. Sin embargo, esto hace que la ejecución sea más lenta. Entonces una forma de optimizar el código de arriba es usando la clase [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), debido a que, nos permite crear objetos mutables y por lo tanto, podemos ir agregando caracteres en el objeto en cada iteración, sin la necesidad de concatenar.

El código quedaría así:

```java
class MyString
{
    private String str;

    public MyString(String str)
    {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
    {
        StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
        int len = str.length();
        for(int i = 0; i != len; ++i)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i) == oldChar) 
                newString.append(newChar);
            else
                newString.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
        return newString.toString();
    }
}
```